# Merge different data files having different values in different column to a single file

Tags: r

I have 4 dataframe, 1st is having only date and time column, 2nd,3rd,and 4th are having all date,time and species column but only 1st have complete date and time and other don't have, Now I need to merge the 4 together in a single file. I have used the code merge to get them together but it doesn't work.

```
mydata4 <- merge(mydata0,mydata1,mydata2,mydata3,by= c( "Date","Time"), all=TRUE)
```

It doesn't work showing error
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 
  'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical

> 

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

Is your Date and Time in the same column? What are the dimensions of each data frame?

You should look into the `xts` package.

First, convert each data frame into a `xts` object by using `as.xts()` function and then use `merge.xts()` function to merge according to Date and Time.